# Is a subset of vectors in $F^4_2$ with an even number of zero entries a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is a subset of vectors in $F^4_2$ with an even number of zero entries a subspace?

*Counterexample*: closure under vector addition using mod $2$ arithmetic with
$u = (0,0,1,1)$ and v = $(1,1,0,0)$

$u + v = (1,1,1,1)$; hence not subspace.

However, the solution manual says it is a subspace

How do you write proof for vector addition and scalar multiplication in mod 2?

Answer (score 1):

Zero is an even number, so $(1,1,1,1)$ has an even number of zero entries.

I assume the vector space in question is $\mathbb{F}_2^4$.

Comment: So (1,1,1,0) has even no of zero entries?

Comment: That has one zero entry.

Comment: Absence of zero entries means zero entries?

Comment: Yes, there are zero zero entries :)